# HOW TO UPLOAD XML TO MULTIPLE TALLY COMPANIES

Tags: xml, tally

I have been uploading xml to Tally.ERP 9 via Excel VBA.
I want to know if it's possible to upload xml to multiple tally companies at once or Not?

My excel data looks like this

| Date | Ledger(cr) | Ledger(dr) | Amount | Narration | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/12/2021 | Zeebank | Bank Charges | 450 | Bank Charges for Dec | ABC |
| 27/12/2021 | IntBank | ODfee | 750 | Bank Charges for Dec | XYZ |
| 30/12/2021 | AfriBank | MgtFee | 150 | Bank Charges for Dec | BAC |

Part of the xml as below

```
    <ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER> 
    <BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
    <REQUESTDESC>
    <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
    <STATICVARIABLES>
    <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Column 6</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
    </STATICVARIABLES>
    </REQUESTDESC>
    <REQUESTDATA>
    <TALLYMESSAGE>
    <VOUCHER REMOTEID="" VCHKEY="" VCHTYPE="Payment"    ACTION="Create"> 
    <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
    <NARRATION> Colum 5 </NARRATION>
    <VOUCHERTYPENAME> Payment </VOUCHERTYPENAME>
    <PARTYLEDGERNAME>" Column 2 </PARTYLEDGERNAME>
    <EFFECTIVEDATE>Column 1</EFFECTIVEDATE>
    <LEDGERNAME>Column 2</LEDGERNAME>
    <AMOUNT>Column 4</AMOUNT>
    </VOUCHER>
    </TALLYMESSAGE>
    </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
    </ENVELOPE>
```

Here is the post method I am using for single company

```
    xmlhttp.Open "post", "http://localhost:9000", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "356"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "localhost:" & UserForm1.txtPort & """"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"

    xmlhttp.send myXMLstr
    MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
```

Any idea on how to do this will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer as per new Data

```
MsgBox Cells(row ,5).value
Startrow = 2
for row = 0 + Startrow to 4
.....other xml
myXMLstr += <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Cells(row ,5).value</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
...other xml
..other code
xmlhttp.send myXMLstr
MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
next row
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I have added a sample of my excel data to the question. Please kindly show how to do this . Thank you.

Comment: based on excel format , adding SVCURRENTCOMPANY tag to static variables in your xml is sufficient no need of companies list array also
For full answer post your XML payload also

Comment: I posted part of the xml in the question. I tried your answer but only one company get imported. Thanks

Comment: Edited answer accordingly

Comment: I receive error on this line myXMLstr +=

Comment: Share your excel file code with VBA

Comment: The question has been updated with details xml and the table represents the excel file.